# How do I set different color schemes with multiple vscode windows open

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two windows open for debugging. One is for my service and the other is for my workbench. They are two different repos so I want them on two different instances of VSCode. I also want to have them be different color schemes. When I change the color scheme in one instance it applies to the other. Is there a way around this? Is there a way to have multiple windows be different color schemes in vscode?

Comment: Does putting   a different   "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai"
into each workspace's .vscode/settings.json work?  Not the user settings.

Answer (score 16):

You can configure the different title-bar color using `.vscode/settings.json`.
(For configuring different color themes, I don't know yet.)

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#5D0D15",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#82131D",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#FEFBFB"
  }
}
```

But, you can easily use the plugin called **[Window Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors)** which automatically generate `.vscode/settings.json` based-on the directory name like hash.

Actually I hope that the color will be better, but nowadays it can be very handy solution.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors

[image: img]

Comment: Keep in mind that `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` have to be inside `"settings": {}`

Answer (score 12):

Changing user settings changes all open instances color theme of VSCode which we do as below.It does not serve the purpose.

[image]

Instead use Workspace settings (Ctrl+Shift+P and type Workspace) and edit the color to your choice. Now it should get changed only to the opened instance.**Mark** in his comment already made this point , I am just elaborating it.Thanks Mark.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There is a Visual Studio Code extension called Peacock which helps to do this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock

Comment: Much prefer peacock to the other options above